# How to add a value to an array without the splice method and overwriting the element? javascript

Tags: javascript, concatenation, splice

Is there a way to concat an array at a specific index without overwriting the element, not using the splice method? I usually see concats happen in the beginning or end of an array.

Below is an example of using splice to concat an array at an index

````
var colors=["red","blue"];
var index=1;

//if i wanted to insert "white" at index 1
colors.splice(index, 0, "white");   //colors =  ["red", "white", "blue"]
```
````

Comment: What's wrong with splice? It's what the method is intended for

Comment: nothing is wrong with it, just wanted to explore other methods

Comment: @pilchard I know I'm a bit late, but `splice` alters the original array and sometimes you don't want that.

Comment: @Towkir I'm well aware, but the OP made no mention of immutability and the accepted answer also mutates the original array. Regardless, `splice` (and `slice` if you're worried about mutation) are very old, stable methods and reinventing the wheel seems unnecessary.

Comment: @pilchard right, got your point, stumbled upon this today and thought OP might have wanted the same thing originally, though the accepted answer says otherwise. 
Anyway, finally ended up copying the original array and then using splice on the copied one, accepted answer is a bit overkill for the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take [`Array#copyWithin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin)
with some adjustments.

```js
const
    colors = ["red", "blue"],
    index = 1,
    value = "white";

colors.length++;                      // create space for moving
colors.copyWithin(index + 1, index);  // move values to right
colors[index] = value;                // add new value

console.log(colors); // ["red", "white", "blue"]
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way, do you know if what the time complexity of this would be?

Comment: it looks like O(n), depending on the elements for shifting.